# AngularJS: Only every other item in ng-model shows in select elements

Tags: angularjs, select, element

The problem is rather simple: in my html I have:

```
<select ng-model="GetuserData.AROM1" ng-options="o as o for o in getvals" /><br />
<select ng-model="GetuserData.AROM2" ng-options="o as o for o in getvals" /><br />
<select ng-model="GetuserData.AROM3" ng-options="o as o for o in getvals" /><br />
<select ng-model="GetuserData.AROM4" ng-options="o as o for o in getvals" /><br />
{{GetuserData.AROM1}}<br />
{{GetuserData.AROM2}}<br />
{{GetuserData.AROM3}}<br />
{{GetuserData.AROM4}}
```

On the rendered page ***it only shows the first and third select boxes*** - 
But it does show all four of the array object items in the scope items included in the double curly brackets.

I've tried every variation that I can imagine but the results are still the same.
***The only thing that works is if I put all of the "select" elements inside table data/ table rows inside a table.***

Comment: Have you tried `<select ...></select>` instead of `<select ... />`? I'm not sure it's allowed to aut-close a select element.

Comment: That's it! Kind of embarrassing - but I am just grateful for your help - Thanks so much!